# I used to be able to use g++ from the terminal, but now it's missing. I still have XCode installed

Tags: terminal, xcode

I used to be able to use g++ from the terminal to compile c++ programs, but now when I try to use it, I get

> -bash: g++: command not found

General advice on the internet was to install XCode, but I already have XCode installed. I'm not sure what has changed since being able to use it. I'm running OSX 10.6.8 and XCode 3.2.4.

Comment: Try reinstalling xcode

Comment: What is your path and what is ib /usr/bin - but easiest to reinstall XCode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this is embarrassing. But reinstalling XCode from the OS X disc DID work. I just didn't think to try it because I already had it installed.

Comment: Not at all - this last step is fragile and still breaks for me more than I'd care to have happen. We've easily got 15 macs where upgrading to Lion sent the dev tools path astray. See [Is there a second step needed to activate the command line tools?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21500/is-there-a-second-step-needed-to-activate-the-command-line-tools-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem at one point with gcc.  gcc and g++ usually link to a version-specific binary.  Look in /Developer/usr/bin for something like g++-x.y, where x.y is the installed version of g++.  You'll probably see gcov, gcc, etc. there as well.  Just create a symbolic link from the versioned g++ to g++.

For example, on my machine, I would type `ln -sf g++-4.2 g++`.

Hope this helps.  If the versioned compiler tools aren't there, you may need to reinstall the Developer Tools.

Comment: I already have a g++ in /Developer/usr/bin. I have g++, g++-4.0 and g++-4.2. Same with gcc

Comment: That's very strange.  What is $PATH set to?  Does it include /Developer/usr/bin?  If you type the absolute path (just for this exercise) /Developer/usr/bin/g++, do you still get the command not found error?

Comment: Using the absolute path works fine. It looks like /Developer isn't in my path. How do I add that? Also, why would it be removed in the first place?

Comment: That's actually pretty weird because I believe a proper Xcode install will also have entries for the compilers in /usr/bin.  To add the /Developer binaries to your path, all you need to do is add `export PATH=$PATH:/Developer/usr/bin` to your .profile, .bash_profile, or .bashrc, whichever you use. `grep PATH .*` will show you which one you use.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one account try executing g++ from the other account. If it works, you probably have an issue with the .bash path definitions.